# Avoid overflow in random matrix multiplication in python

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, overflow, matrix-multiplication

I have to multiply many (about 700) matrices with a random element (in the following, I'm using a box distribution) in python:

```
#define parameters
μ=2.
σ=2.
L=700

#define random matrix
T=[None]*L


product=np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
for i in range(L):
    m=np.random.uniform(μ-σ*3**(1/2), μ+σ*3**(1/2)) #box distribution
    T[i]=np.array([[-1,-m/2],[1,0]])
    product=product.dot(T[i])  #multiplying matrices

Det=abs(np.linalg.det(product))
print(Det)
```

For this choice of μ and σ, I obtain quantities of the order of e^30+, but this quantity should converge to 0. How do I know? Because analytically it can be demonstrated to be equivalent to:

```
Y=[None]*L
product1=np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
for i in range(L):
    m=np.random.uniform(μ-σ*(3**(1/2)), μ+σ*(3**(1/2))) #box distribution
    Y[i]=np.array([[-m/2,0],[1,0]])
    product1=product1.dot(Y[i])
    
l,v=np.linalg.eig(product1)

print(abs(l[1]))
```

which indeed gives e^-60.
I think there is an overflow issue here. How can I fix it?

**EDIT:**

The two printed quantities are expected to be equivalent because the first one is the abs of the determinant of:

[image: product]

which is, according to the *Binet theorem* (the determinant of a product is the product of determinants):

[image: determinant]

The second code prints the abs of the greatest eigenvalue of:

[image: product1]

It is easy to see that one eigenvalue is 0, the other equals [image: determinant].

Comment: Why do you expect these to be analytically equivalent? Why do you need 0 and e^-60 is not good enough? Where is the overflow? Clarify the question please

Comment: @NikolayZakirov e^-60 is very good. I would like the first code to go to e^-60 too, but it diverges to e^+30.  How can I add equations to this answer, in order to show you why these two quantities should be equivalent?

Comment: @NikolayZakirov I tried to explain it with an edit to the post

Comment: Looks good, changed my downvote )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally a hard problem. There are a few nice articles about floating point arightmetics and precision. Here is a famous [one](https://www.soa.org/news-and-publications/newsletters/compact/2014/may/com-2014-iss51/losing-my-precision-tips-for-handling-tricky-floating-point-arithmetic/)

One of the general tricks - use a scale variable. Like this:

```
import numpy as np
#define parameters
μ=2.
σ=2.
L=700

#define random matrix
T=[None]*L

scale = 1
product=np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
for i in range(L):
    m=np.random.uniform(μ-σ*3**(1/2), μ+σ*3**(1/2)) #box distribution
    T[i]=np.array([[-1,-m/2],[1,0]])
    product=np.matmul(product, T[i])  #multiplying matrices
    scale *= abs(product[0][0])
    product /= abs(product[0][0])

Det=abs(np.linalg.det(product*scale))
print(Det)
```

It makes things a little better but unfortunately doesn't help.

In this particular case what you can do is multiply the determinants instead of matrices. Like this:

```
import numpy as np
#define parameters
μ=2.
σ=2.
L=700

#define random matrix
T=[None]*L

scale = 1
product=1
for i in range(L):
    m=np.random.uniform(μ-σ*3**(1/2), μ+σ*3**(1/2)) #box distribution
    T[i]=np.array([[-1,-m/2],[1,0]])
    product *= np.linalg.det(T[i])  #multiplying matrices determinants
    
Det=abs(product)
print(Det)
```

The output:

```
1.1081329233309736e-61
```

So this cures the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful and ansewers to my question. However, I was actually look for a kind of solution which would improve the precision of calculations without bypassing the problem with mathematical manipulations. That's because the problem I have exposed up here is part of a bigger problem that I did not want to insert here in order to synthesize, that is the computation of the eigenvalues of the first product of matrices, which I knew that usually are computed wrongly (if I use np.linalg-eig) because of the reasoning about the determinant. How can I solve, in general, the overflow?

Comment: I posted a general method too in my answer. Although it didn't help in this case. Keep the sum terms of similar magnitude. Mathematical manipulations would certainly fit better. Think whether you can do any

Comment: Please accept my answer if it answers your question

Answer (score 1):

I will take `m` instead of `m/2` to simplify the formulae, but it does not change anything.

The product of first two mtrices is

```
[-1  -m1 ] * [-1 -m2 ] = [1-m1  m2 ]
[ 1   0  ]   [ 1  0  ]   [-1   -m2 ]
```

if you take the det, that is `(-m2+m1*m2) + m2`
You can see a form of cancellation of bigger terms (m2), resulting in the statistically smaller `m1*m2`

After 2 multiplications it's getting worse

```
[m1+m2-1  m1*m3-m3 ]
[ 1-m2       m3    ]
```

the det is `(m1*m3+m2*m3-m3)+(m1*m2*m3-m2*m3-m1*m3+m3)`
Once again, the magnitude of the two terms is that of `m3`
while the result is smaller `m1*m2*m3`.

A few operations will invariably lead to cases of catastrophic cancellation
`(big+small)-big`

The numerical noise in the calculation of `big` largely exceeed the magnitude of exact result.

That indicates that the problem cannot be mitigated by simple scaling, the matrix is somehow ill-conditioned by design.

You can try and transform the random into a rational (a float value is rational), and evaluate the product with rationals (infinite precision), but with 700 terms, expect very large integers and very slow computation...

Comment: Thanks, this is a thourough investigation